# Bash script to split logs based on file size

Tags: bash, logs, java, logrotate

I'm working on a .bash script that kicks off a Java program, logs the sysouts to an 'outfile', then **appends** the log results for historical purposes to a 'archive' zip. My current script is like below...

```
outfile=/some/log/directory/templog-$(date +%s).log
archive=/some/log/directory/archive.log.gz
java -cp MyJar.jar Logger 2>&1 | tee $outfile | gzip - | cat - >> $archive
```

What i'd like to do is, if the temp file reaches a size of 2GB, create a new file like 'outfile2', 'outfile3', etc., then when all is done, zip all the resulting 'outfile's into the 'archive'.gz file (or maybe just zip it up into individual files)

I was looking into the 'rotatelogs' vs. 'logrotate' but can't seem to figure out what my best option is, i'm a noob in the linux world so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: gzip after tee does compress stdout (not outfile) and what's the purpose of cat?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that instead of zipping early, you can zip it via logrotate. You can write a [logrotate](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/) file which can be triggered every few mins via cron, which will check file size, and will rotate it, and also compress it.

Alternatively you can use the **split** command. This command can split a file based on size or number of lines. This would make you command as:

```
java -cp MyJar.jar Logger 2>&1 | tee $outfile | gzip | split -m 2048m archive
```

From tee the data/output will go into gzip which will compress the data, and this data goes into split, which will split the output when it reaches 2Gb in size.